# Error, missing TClient parameter

Tags: c#, .net, api, dll, google-drive-api

I am following the google QuickStart google Drive .NET api video and I get an error at this point. I followed everything they said, I added all the required dlls. I am running windows 7 on a virutal machine, with Visual Studio 2012, could this be the issue?

After copy pasting their code, I cannot build it.
I get this error :

`OAuth2.OAuth2Authenticator<TClient>' requires 1 type arguments`

I could not find any info on google about this error , nor about the TClient

What is my missing TClient parameter?

**The code**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data;
using Google.Apis.Util;

namespace GoogleDriveSamples
{
    class DriveCommandLineSample
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String CLIENT_ID = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
            String CLIENT_SECRET = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET";

            // Register the authenticator and create the service
            var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
            var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(provider, GetAuthorization);
            var service = new DriveService(auth);

            File body = new File();
            body.Title = "My document";
            body.Description = "A test document";
            body.MimeType = "text/plain";

            byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("document.txt");
            System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

            FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "text/plain");
            request.Upload();

            File file = request.ResponseBody;
            Console.WriteLine("File id: " + file.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to end this process.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient arg)
        {
            // Get the auth URL:
            IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { DriveService.Scopes.Drive.GetStringValue() });
            state.Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);
            Uri authUri = arg.RequestUserAuthorization(state);

            // Request authorization from the user (by opening a browser window):
            Process.Start(authUri.ToString());
            Console.Write("  Authorization Code: ");
            string authCode = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Retrieve the access token by using the authorization code:
            return arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode, state);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a setup or configuration issue in your solution. Try following the step-by-step instructions in the video recording of the Google Developers Live session where the .NET Drive quickstart is covered:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uwrJSWqglTc